# Empty Help Center page "Collectives on Stack Overflow" on other network sites should be removed

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, collectives

I've just found that help center on any site contains a link to Collectives on Stack Overflow, [e.g. here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/coso):

> [image: Empty Collectives]

But the page is empty. It seems that that page should only be visible for Stack Overflow, where [the page has actual content](https://stackoverflow.com/help/coso):

> [image: Collectives on SO]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention! This indeed shouldn't be there on non-SO sites. We'll update this post when the bug is fixed.

**Update Oct 20th 2021**

This should be fixed now, let us know if we've missed something.

Comment: Huh, you and Yaakov working together on this?

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 Yaakov pinged our team on this subject when he saw this meta post and proposed a solution that our team is implementing.

Comment: Perfect team work, awesome. Good luck with implementing! :-)