# Empty help section Staging Ground except Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, staging-ground

There's empty section [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/staging-ground) on Help Center for any site exception Stack Overflow:

> [image]

Should this section be removed at all if not available for current site yet?

Comment: It can't be removed per-site, technically, their code does not support it as far as I can tell. The content however can be made bit more friendly by e.g. "Staging Ground is a project on Stack Overflow, to learn more please go to its Help Center".

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard why do you think it can't be removed per-site? See similar BR about [Collectives.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370908/339911)

Comment: [Challenge accepted]

Comment: @Yaakov well if there's someone who can perform miracles more than once, that would be you. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And thus the mysterious Staging Ground lurking around unsuspecting stack exchange help centers was no more.